# updating ALB inbound-cidrs annotations leads to merge error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a list of cidrs I want to grant access to my application defined as such:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/inbound-cidrs: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32, etc.
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80,"HTTPS":443}]'
```

When I add a new cidr and deploy again, I get this error from the aws-load-balancer-controller:

```
failed to merge listenPort config for port: 443: conflicting inbound-cidrs
```

where it'll also show the conflict between the old ingress rules (old cidrs list) and the new ones (old cidrs list + new cidsr added).

I've tried a rollout restart of the aws-load-balancer-controller, but the error persists.

Anyone know how to get the new cidrs annotations applied?

Answer (score 0):

you might have a duplicate CIDR ranges, check it out
or else you might be creating two different ingresses with same cidr ranges to single load balancer, in that case also, it ll give an error.

Have cidr ranges only at one place and avoid duplicate cidr ranges

Answer (score 0):

temp fix: commented out the inbound-cidrs annotation, no more merge conflict. Just still can't add new cidr blocks to the ingress rules.

edit: seems like not being able to edit/delete ingress rules is an existing [problem](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/1629).